# How to remove specific value from comma separated cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am using jQuery cookie plugin to store image names with comma separated in one cookie. Now I am little bit confused how to remove specific value from cookie.

For example I have added bellow jQuery code:

```
jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added') + ', ' + a.name);
```

And I am getting this result:

```
undefined, Chrysanthemum.jpg, Desert.jpg
```

Now I want to remove `undefined` value from cookie then update cookie value, after that same things `Chrysanthemum.jpg`.

As you understand that I want to update cookie value.

Is it possible as I have not good knowledge with jQuery. I will happy if you help me :)

Thanks.

Comment: The first time this code is run, the `dropzone_added` cookie does not exist hence `undefined` is appended. I would fix that problem, rather than hack a string around.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please guide me how to fix that and how to update jQuey cookie :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove `undefined` from the string if you prevent it from being added in the first place.

The first time this code executes, the cookie will not exist, hence you are appending the word `undefined` to the string. If you change your logic to check for the existence of the cookie, you can avoid this:

```
var cookieVal = jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added');
jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', cookieVal ? cookieVal + ', ' + a.name : a.name);
```

Comment: Hey that's great help and It's working perfect but I am still want to understand how to update cookie value because sometimes I want to update cookie value also.

Comment: For example If I am holding this value like `Chrysanthemum.jpg, Desert.jpg, Tulips.jpg` and I want to remove `Chrysanthemum.jpg` from cookie. How it is possible??

Comment: This will update the cookie value for you too. If you want to remove a known value, Rachits regex method would work.

Comment: Okay I will try first and If not works I will tell :)

Comment: Hi as you told you to try @Rachits code but it is not working. I have created jsFiddle so can you check. http://jsfiddle.net/d6rs5/

Comment: Is it possible to add one comma to the last value. Like `Chrysanthemum.jpg, Desert.jpg, Hydrangeas.jpg, Jellyfish.jpg,`

Answer (score 0):

Below code will check cookie has value or not and append value only when cookies has value

```
if (typeof jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added') === "undefined") {
  jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', a.name);
else
  jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added') + ', ' + a.name);
```

to replace/remove any value you can use sring.replace() function

```
var cookieValue = jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added');
cookieValue.replace(/Chrysanthemum.jpg/gi, 'new value')
jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', cookieValue);
```

Comment: but after sring.replace() how to reinitialize again with updated cookie.

Comment: Okay I let me try then I will ping you :)

Comment: Hi I have two question 1. I am getting image name in variable like this `a.name` so how to pass inside this `/Chrysanthemum.jpg/gi` 2. It will also remove that image name with his comma??

Comment: instead of 'new value' put a.name  cookieValue.replace(/Chrysanthemum.jpg/gi, a.name) and i am not understanding your 2nd question

Comment: I don't want to rename any cookie but I want to delete that value.

Comment: jQuery.cookie('dropzone_added', '');  this way you can delete existing cookie value

Comment: possible then add your code in fiddle so, I can check your code and make necessary change in your code however i am going to creationg fillde of my code to understand you

Comment: Hey I have created jsFiddle can you please check again and correct me. http://jsfiddle.net/d6rs5/

Comment: Hey I need small help and I will happy If you give me your small support because I am very close to complete this task. I am using @Rort McCrossan code which mention bellow. Now I want to add comma to end of the string just like this: `Lighthouse.jpg, Penguins.jpg, Tulips.jpg,`

Comment: Have you check my code/fiddle? I have written code to Add , Replace , Remove and show cookie value.

Comment: Hi I have checked and also implemented so thanks again but check my last comment.